# Create a turn routing flow with SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I'm trying to query a route based on the origin and destination using SQL.

This is the data I have

| Origin | Destination | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MUC | LHR | 5 |
| MUC | CDG | 2 |
| CDG | LHR | 6 |

This is the Output, I'm trying to display:

| Origin | Destination | Revenue | Route |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MUC | LHR | 5 | MUC-LHR |
| CDG | LHR | 8 | MUC-CDG-LHR |

Thanks in advance

I have tried to use CTE and Loop but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive CTE is the correct way of doing this.

This one will look something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE route AS
(
    SELECT origin, 
        destination, 
        revenue, 
        origin || '-' || destination as route
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE origin='MUC'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT yt.origin, 
        yt.destination, 
        rt.revenue + yt.revenue, 
        rt.route || '-' || yt.destination
    FROM route rt
        INNER JOIN yourtable yt
            ON rt.destination = yt.origin
)
SELECT * 
FROM route
WHERE route.route LIKE 'MUC%LHR'
```

Comment: Thank you ! But if I would like to automate this process on a large scale database, how should I do it please ?

Comment: It totally depends on what you mean by "automate". Ultimately this logic is the base. You could take out the two where clauses and give it a run and you'll see every interim record for every possible `origin` and its path to every possible `destination`, if that's what you are after.